# Why doesn't my VBA function work properly?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA and programming, so this might be a dumb question. I have written the following code:

```
Function central(X)

 Dim xc(300, 10), xa(200)
 m = X.Rows.Count
 n = X.Columns.Count


For j = 1 To n
xa(j) = 0

   For i = 1 To m
     xa(j) = xa(j) + X(i, j)
   Next i
xa(j) = xa(j) / m

For i = 1 To m
     xc(i, j) = X(i, j) - xa(j)

Next i
Next 

central = xc()


End Function
```

This should output a matrix whose elements are subtracted from the average value of their columns.

My problem is that the output is shifted with one row and column. So for example for this table:

```
1 1 1 
2 2 2 
3 3 3
```

it gives me:

```
0 0 0
0 -1 -1 
0 0 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: using `Dim xc(300, 10), xa(200)` gives you zero-based arrays. Try to use `Dim xc(1 to 300, 1 to 10), xa(1 to 200)`

Comment: Btw, there is no need to use UDF. You can use simple formula. Say your data in `A1:B3`. Than write this formula in acy cell: `=A1-SUM(A$1:A$3)/ROWS(A$1:A$3)` and drag it dows and across

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Yes, I know, I can do it without a function, I was just practicing VBA.